# Using calculation to set state asynchronizely

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

I have an axios call, where I want to setState in my component, but one of the state variables, requires some conditional logic, on rather what to set the state. Now I'm in doubt, of what is the best practice to do this

```
   }).then(res =>
       this.setState({
           name: res.data.fname,
           sName: res.data.sname,
           percentage: res.data.percentage,
           result: res.data.result,
           showResult: true,
           type: this.typeHandler(this.state.percentage) // here a tried calling a handler to make my conditional setState call
       })
       )
       }


typeHandler = (percentage) =>{
    if(percentage >= 50){
        this.setState({type: 'succes'})
    }else{
        this.setState({type: 'failure'})
    }
    }
```

of course, the issue with this code is that it will happen asynchronized, and therefore the state, will not be set correct initially.

Is there a better way to improve this logic, so the state is set along with the other attributes initially, and I can include my logic?

I guess the alternative, would be to get the percentage first, and then just call the handler after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using state in setState, you could use res.data.percentage. Also the typeHandler must return a value instead of setting it in state given that you are already calling it in setState

```
}).then(res =>
       this.setState({
           name: res.data.fname,
           sName: res.data.sname,
           percentage: res.data.percentage,
           result: res.data.result,
           showResult: true,
           type: this.typeHandler(res.data.percentage) 
       })
   )}


typeHandler = (percentage) =>{
    if(percentage >= 50){
        return 'succes';
    }else{
        return 'failure';
    }
}
```